# Why is string concatenation in my SELECT statement not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query of the form

```
SELECT '(''' + 
       SomeVarCharColumn + 
       ''',' + 
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), SomeIntColumn) + 
       ',' + 
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), SomeOtherIntColumn) 
       + ')' 
FROM SomeTable
```

and all the results are `NULL`. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you have a NULL in one or more of your values.  String + null = null

Answer (score 2):

`null + 1` is `null`
`null + 'things'` is `null`

try this instead:

```
select '('''
    + isnull(somevarcharcolumn,'')
    + ''','
    + isnull(convert(nvarchar(max), someintcolumn),'null')
    + ','
    + isnull(convert(nvarchar(max), someotherintcolumn),'null')
    + ')' 
from sometable
```

Answer (score 2):

If any column is `NULL`, then the value is `NULL`.  Use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT '(''' + COALESCE(SomeVarCharColumn, '') + ''',' +
       COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), SomeIntColumn), '') + ',' + 
       COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), SomeOtherIntColumn), '') + ')'
FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CONCAT() function. When null values are encountered they are simply omitted from the resulting string. Additionally, int to char conversions are implicit no need for the convert, you can find a chart of implicit conversions here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('(''',SomeVarCharColumn,''',',SomeIntColumn,',',SomeOtherIntColumn,')') AS NewVarchar
FROM SomeTable
```